# Why does the sky after sunset mimic the blackbody spectrum?

Tags: optics, visible-light, thermal-radiation, atmospheric-science

There are several answers on this site and elsewhere about why the sky is blue and why sunsets are reddish. But I could not find anything that discusses the relationship between the blackbody spectrum and the spectrum of colors seen above the horizon after sunset.

[image]

[image]

In particular, the "physical spectrum" (meaning the set of colors seen in the sky at increasing altitude above the horizon) after sunset looks identical to the blackbody spectrum. Perhaps this is related to the fact that sunlight is approximately blackbody to begin with, but I can't find any source that discusses this. For example, consider the following questions:

1. If sunlight had an "even" spectrum in the visible range, instead of blackbody, would sunsets look considerably different? Would they stop looking like the blackbody spectrum?
2. Is the color spectrum at each fixed location in the sky actually a blackbody spectrum (whose color temperature varies with altitude), or only approximately a blackbody spectrum? (Assume even that the sun *is* a perfect blackbody.)
3. Since sunlight is blackbody, is it inevitable that any type of scattering would create a blackbody-like gradation of colors in the sky, i.e., not necessarily Rayleigh scattering?

In short, why does the physical spectrum of colors seen in the sky after sunset mimic the blackbody spectrum?

Comment: The "blackbody spectrum" you showed first is just a representation of perceived colour vs temperature of the black body. Not an actual spectrum. This is all just a coincidence.... (for example, the sun's colour in the first image is between 5500 and 6000...actually close to our perception of white)

Comment: I agree with the first statement—perhaps I should have avoided the term "blackbody spectrum" to refer to a set of colors. But the statement that this is a coincidence doesn't seem to follow (and I find it hard to believe).

Comment: why not? Sky is blue due to scattering and so is the red sunset. A sunset in mars looks blueish due to different atmospheric contents. The first image is about squeezing a whole spectrum to one single color, each individual layer of the sky's colour ***is*** that colour.

Comment: But why? I could imagine Rayleigh scattering shifting the overall color of each portion of the sky in such a way that the result looks nothing like the blackbody colors. But this is not the case.

Comment: Or let me add a different take on your questions: the sun's output lies in the 5500 to 6000K of the first image. 1. An even spectrum in the VIS would look green, sunset would probably still look red. 2.No. 3. no.

Comment: Exactly, scattering could have worked differently, Its a coincidence and nothing to do with blackbody radiation on the sky. I think you need to understand that the first image is a squeezed 2D graph, not a $x$ with an associated colour.

Comment: If the sky would be made of olive oil, the sunset would look super weird and not at all like any gradation associated to a blackbody spectrum for example. Scattering would be completely different (I wonder how it would really look like as olive oil fluoresces orange when excited by violet/UV light).

Comment: another example, at 12000, color representation is blue, because that's the peak emission. The sky is not that colour because it is at 12000K, or because scattering makes it imitate a black body radiation of a 12000K body. On the contrary, the sky has a more defined "emission spectrum" that resembles the colour posted for 12000K. Your monitor is also showing those colors, and in both cases its not because they are blackbody radiators.

Comment: I am not suggesting that the sky appears to have the color of a blackbody at temperature $T$ because it actually *is* at that temperature. It just seems that there is some reason the sky appears to be all of these colors, and not any of the colors outside this set. "Most colors" are not the apparent color of any blackbody, as chromaticity diagrams often indicate.

Comment: I think its a coincidence...the blackbody radiation distribution does not follow the scattering "strength". Like I said, if we lived under olive oil, scattering would be incredibly different and would not produce the same shades of colors. Or underwater. Of course in those cases we are in a medium that absorbs also strongly. Alternatively you can plot/check the scaling of the variables for blackbody radiation vs rayleigh scattering. Or compare the spectrum of the blue sky to a blackbody radiator with for example 8000k.

Comment: (do not get me completely wrong, I now understand where you want to get, but I still think that its all just coincidence. The sky scatters the present colours, so it would mostly look blue, if blue is there (at peak of day). And look reddish at sunset (if present) because blue is gone. I'm now trying to imagine what a much denser atmosphere would do...or different constitution)

Answer (score 2):

Red/orange, white and blue are the colors you see when the intensity of light as a function of frequency (or wavelength) is very roughly linear across the visible range. To get other hues, you need narrow peaks or troughs in the spectrum, and Rayleigh scattering and blackbodies don't produce such spectra for different reasons.

Spectra from Rayleigh scattering are monotonic in the frequency. Blackbody spectra of different temperatures are all translated copies of a single shape on a log chart, as seen here:

[image]

At around 6000 K the visible part is roughly flat (white), at lower temperatures it's brighter at the red end, and at higher temperatures it's brigher at the violet end (but not sharply peaked there, so it appears blue, not violet).

So it's coincidence in the sense that Rayleigh scattering and blackbody emission are totally different processes, but not coincidence in the sense that you can expect to get similar colors from any physical process that doesn't produce narrow peaks or troughs in the spectrum.